# What is the maximum size of an apk on Google Glass?

Tags: android, google-glass

I'm trying to get started with Google Glass development and I've been looking over different informative sites and blogs but was not able gather the information I am looking for.

What is the max size of an .apk for an application I can deploy on Google Glass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum size limit of an individual APK is the same as on other Android devices: 50 MB.

Comment: i want know the Max size of .apk for google glass applications

Comment: Google Glass uses the same 50 MB limit for APKs as other Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as that of a normal android device!

The maximum size of an APK is 50 MB to be hosted on the play store, but you can have 2 expansion files with a maximum size of 2GB each.

I think the 50 MB is a security limit and it might not be a play store only restriction, not sure if a 50 MB would be installed on a device, never tried.

Comment: i want know the Max size of .apk for google glass applications

Comment: Are you sure about it. due have any personal experience or referred some blogs or wiki's. (Just a concern before i get into any conclusion )